# Performance problem of java.lang.Thread and threads in ThreadPool

Tags: multithreading, apache-kafka, threadpool, executorservice, consumer

A Kafka consumer application has severe latencies (not consuming the kafka events fast enough during the peak hour). The kafka topic has 120 partitions, and the consumer group has a total of 30 hosts, and each host has two consumers, so each consumer consumes from 2 kafka partitions. The hosts we use are AWS C5.9xlarge instances with 32cores. Each consumer was put into one java.lang.Thread, and within each thread, a ThreadPool is created with 250 threads.

We have verified that the none of the CPU/Memory/IO is bottleneck. Then we increased the 250 workers to 500 workers, but latency stayed. Then we changed back to 250 workers, but increased to 4 consumers per host from 2. As a result, each consumer consumes from one kafka partition. And now problem is solved, the latency dropped to very low.

My question is, why increasing from 250 to 500 in the Threadpool did not help, but increasing from 2 to 4 consumers per host helped?

```
private class ConsumerThread extends Thread {
    public ConsumerThread(StremProcessor processor) {
      this.processor = processor;
      this.consumer = new KafkaConsumer()
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(250);
        while (true) {
          Data data = consumer.poll()
          executor.invokeAll(getTasks(data, processor)); //processor is 
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thread pool is nothing but a `reusable` pool of `java.lang.Thread`. Generally, Thread pool has a `queue of tasks` and if any thread from the thread pool is free it can execute the task and when the task is done that Thread back to the pool and try to find if there any other task waiting in the queue.

> How are the threads in ThreadPool different from the java.lang.Thread?

There is no difference. Only the difference in usage.

> Is it because all the threads in the ThreadPool use a single
>   processor core?

No, it can use any number of available processor.

> I remember that the default threads in the ExecutorPool is 250 per
>   processor, does that mean the ExecutorPool is not smart enough to
>   distribute the 250 threads to 16 cores?

From where you get the info like " ExecutorPool is 250 per processor"?. I don't understand your question completely. A Thread pool's thread can execute on any core as normal thread there is no restrictions for Thread pool's thread.

Comment: Thanks for replying!! The real question is:  why increasing from 250 to 500 in the Threadpool did not help, but increasing from 2 to 4 consumers per host helped? I am asking this is, since the ThreadPool threads is the same with java.lang.Thread, and both the two approaches have 1000 (500*2 or 250*4) threads effectively, why the performance is different?

Answer (score 0):

**First of all:** You should include some delay in your while-loop between each cycle to prevent your application from flooding your memory.

Basically the `ExecutorService.invokeAll()` method returns a list of `Future`s. You can use them to "control" your threads.

> How are the threads in ThreadPool different from the java.lang.Thread?

They do not differ but you get a wrapper (`Future`) back which let you control the thread at execution time. The underlying `Thread` works like a usual Java thread.

> Is it because all the threads in the ThreadPool use a single processor
>   core?

No

Comment: Thanks for replying!! The real question is: why increasing from 250 to 500 in the Threadpool did not help, but increasing from 2 to 4 consumers per host helped? The reason I am asking this is, since the ThreadPool threads is the same with java.lang.Thread, and both the two approaches have 1000 (500*2 or 250*4) threads effectively, why the performance is different?